# PHP - Как записать в БД информацию после оплаты?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день,совсем поверхностно знаком с php, есть небольшой сайт, пользователь вписывает определенные данные, прикрепляет пару фотографий(или не прикрепляет) после этого попадает на страницу оплаты.

Как в данном случае реализовать добавление в базу информации о нем только после оплаты? 
(ну и загрузку фотографий соответственно)

Comment: Оплата-то как происходит?

Comment: через Интеркассу

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, но у вас очень абстрактный вопрос, если вы хотите что бы за вас написали код, идите например на фриланс, если же хотите что бы вам помогли, покажите код, что где, не работает, какие ошибки, и думаю вам помогут

Comment: @R.Key Вот у интеркассы должен быть callback, действие которое совершается после успешной оплаты. Начните от туда.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный алгоритм действий будет следующий:

1. Сначала принимаем заказ от пользователя, загружаем фото и так далее. В базе в соответствующем поле помечаем что заказ не оплачен. Если нужно, просим решить капчу.
2. Посылаем пользователя на оплату.
3. После оплаты помечаем заказ как оплаченный, пишем письмо администратору и так далее.